Error: did not find expected authorization request details in session, req.session["oidc:login.microsoftonline.com"] is undefined
I am trying to use Microsoft IAM with openid-client and passport for the node.js application but I am getting the above error. I read some of the answers posted related to this question but none of them solved my issue. I tried to console the session-id and my session-id changes when it passes /auth.
This is my session code
app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: app.get('sessionSecret'),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 180000 },
    store: MongoStore.create({
      ttl: 180000,
      mongoUrl: `mongodb://${app.get('mongoUser')}:${app.get(
        'mongoPass'
      )}@${app.get('mongoHost')}/botfrontend?authSource=admin`,
      autoRemove: 'interval',
      autoRemoveInterval: 60,
      touchAfter: 24 * 3600,
      secret: app.get('sessionSecret'),
    }),
  })
);

This is my authentication code
  Issuer.discover(app.get('openIdIssuer'))
    .then(
      (issuer) => {
        logger.info(`Found issuer: ${issuer.issuer}.`, {
          issuer: issuer.metadata,
        });
        this._client = new issuer.Client({
          client_id: app.get('openIdClientId'),
          client_secret: app.get('openIdClientSecret'),
          redirect_uris: [app.get('openIdRedirectURL')],
          response_types: ['code'],
        });
        return this._client;
      },
      (err) => {
        logger.error(
          `Error finding issuer for ${app.get('openIdIssuer')}! ${err.message}`
        );
        throw err;
      }
    )
    .then(
      (client) => {
        return client;
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      }
    )
    .then((client) => {
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());

      passport.use(
        'oidc',
        new Strategy(
          {
            client,
            params: {
              scope: app.get('openIdClaims'),
            },
          },
          (tokenSet, done) => {
            return done(null, tokenSet.claims());
          }
        )
      );

      passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user);
      });
      passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user);
      });

      app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('oidc', {
          successRedirect: req.session.returnTo || '/',
          failureRedirect: '/error',
        })(req, res, next);
      });

      app.get('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('oidc',{})(req, res, next);
      });

      app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        const botId = req.session.returnTo;
        const accessToken = req.user.tokenSet.access_token;
        // Get rid of the session token. Then call `logout`; it does no harm.
        req.session.destroy(async function (err) {
          if (err) {
            res.render('error', err);
          }
          req.logout();
          try {
            res.redirect(
              client.endSessionUrl({
                post_logout_redirect_uri: botId,
              })
            );
          } catch (err) {
            await client.revoke(accessToken, 'access_token');
            res.redirect(botId || '/');
          }
        });
      });
    });

